# Trying to explain trig in terms algebra 1, help? (not including Taylor series)?

Tags: geometry

So, I've started out on this formula that I've been spending about a week trying to complete.

θ = degrees

n = 1 (if θ is less than 180 degrees) **or**

n = -1(if θ is greater than 180).

**Sine =**   $$\frac{ (θ+(180 * n) )}{((( θ + ( 180 * n )) 
/tangentθ))/cosineθ}$$

**Sine (Using rearranged Principles) =**

Hypotnuse = adjacent/cosine

Adjacent = opposite/tangent

Cosine = adjacent/hypotenuse

Tangent = Opposite/Adjacent

$$\frac{ opposite }{hypotenuse= (((opposite)) 
/tangentθ))/cosineθ}$$
Since sine is equivalent to both opposite/hypotenuse of theta (this sign right here; θ), it works well.
The numerator of the equation is equivalent to the opposite of θ degrees.

**But *one* problem that still remains!** **I have trouble finding the adjacent of theta degrees in order to find the hypotenuse for the denominator,  without including the tangent or cosine in the formula. We just need to encounter some way to find the hypotenuse or the adjacent like how the opposite of theta was found... I assume?

For favor,

May someone quickly, come with help please?**

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown